# Error running Classify repeatedly within Manipulate

Tags: manipulate, machine-learning

To create a CDF document, I have to run Classify in Manipulate. However, if the code is executed as follows, Classify continues to run repeatedly. Can it be executed and stopped only once?

```
data = Import["data.m"]; 
Manipulate[ Row[{ result = Classify[data], Information[result]}], 
            ContinuousAction -> None]
```

Comment: Why do you use "Manipulate" if there are no parameters to manipulate? Did you mean "Module" or "Block"?

Comment: No. I want to make a CDF document using the Manipulate function.